# Poisson Probability Question (another)

Tags: probability

Suppose the number of average visits per hour at the ATM of a local TD bank follows a Poisson Distribution with lambda = 5 . On  average, customers take $300$ from the ATM per visit. Denote total withdrawal by W. What is the probability that $P(W\ge1800)$.

What confuses me is that how can $\lambda$ be = $5$ and yet the average withdrawal is $300.

I thought lambda is the expected value of a Poisson Distribution? If so, how can the average also be $300?

This problem doesn't simply involve using $\lambda$ = 5 as the parameter and then calculating $P(X\ge 1800)$ because the value of $300 has to be considered as well in the problem. I have no intuition for what's happening here. Any suggestions and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The $\lambda$ is the number of people that visit per hour, which is distinct from how much each person withdraws from the ATM. Since the actual distribution of how much each person withdraws is not given to you, you may assume each person withdraws exactly $300.

Comment: This is confusing and possibly garbled. $\lambda$ is the rate parameter. It is independent of the average withdrawal amount (which seems to be given as $\$300$, but that's not clear). You just have to compute the probability that at least  $6$ people visit in an hour.

Comment: sorry for the grammar and sentence structure not being clear. What I typed in the box did not completely translate when I hit the submit button.

Comment: Please do not clarify in comments. You should [edit] the question. Do that.

Comment: Thank you, Ethan. Computing the probability that at least 6 people visit in an hour makes sense. I thought that was the correct way to go, but then I thought to myself, "that is too easy."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that W represents the total amount withdrawn *in one hour*.

If $X \sim Poi(\lambda)$, since the average withdrawal per visit is 300 dollars, $P(W \geq 1800)$ is the same thing as $P(X \geq \dfrac{1800}{300}) = P(X \geq 6)$.

Everything is now back in terms of the original Poisson distribution. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much for your clear answer. I thought that was the way approach the problem from the beginning, but I often gloss over the obvious, am somehow resistant to solutions that are the most intuitive, thinking the solution must be more difficult, finding out again and again, that often times, the intuitive choice is the correct one. Do I ever learn? I ask myself this question all the time.

Comment: @Maundermin Of course, no problem! If this answer was helpful to you, I'd appreciate if you could mark it as the correct answer. Thank you.